# Changing the keyboard shortcut to go to next/previous tab in Acrobat DC

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-acrobat, tabs

By default, the keyboard shortcut to go to the next/previous tab in Acrobat DC 2015  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>  respectively.

How can I change the keyboard shortcut to go to the next/previous tab in Acrobat DC 2015? I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> instead.

I use Acrobat DC 2015 with Microsoft Windows 10.

---

@MSC  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> is used in many programs e.g. Google Chrome or Eclipse.  I would prefer not to remap keys system-wide as  [sharpkeys](http://alternativeto.net/software/sharpkeys/) would do. It is also more RSI-safe.

Comment: The default shortcuts are the same in most programs. I do not recommend to change them. That said, there is a tool that allows you remapping keys, called [SharpKeys](http://alternativeto.net/software/sharpkeys/). You might want to have a look at it.

Comment: @MSC  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> is used in many programs e.g. Google Chrome or Eclipse.  I would prefer not to remap keys system-wide.

Comment: Indeed, never used it before. But seems that Ctrl+Tab is used even more often. Write to the developers at Adobe and request this for the next version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally there should be an option to change keyboard bindings somewhere in the program. I don't have it myself so I can't look for it, but you should clearly start there.

Assuming you've checked for this already, you could use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> instead - or to have it send both - only in Acrobat DC (you can also remap <kbd>PageUp</kbd> to <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but I imagine you don't want to do that). Same for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>.

Here is an AutoHotkey script that reassigns, i.e. doesn't also send the original key combination (I'm assuming the title of the window has the string "Acrobat DC" in it; otherwise change it to whatever it does say):

```
#IfWinActive, Acrobat DC
^PgUp::^Tab
^PgDown::^+Tab
```

You can add a tilde (`~`) before `^PgUp` and `^PgDown` if you want it to also retain its original function, i.e. send both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>.
To use, simply install the program, put the script in a file and run it.

You can find a list of all the keys supported by AutoHotkey [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).